# Botón pulsado formulario html5

Tags: html5, css

Tengo una duda: Al rellenar un formulario y al pulsar el botón de Save, este se queda pulsado, ¿Porqué pasa esto?. Hace correctamente la introducción de datos pero se queda pulsado el botón. No se si habría que indicar con alguna propiedad en el botón.

```
<a href class="button submit" onclick="addprueba(dni1);">Save</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

La etiqueta `<a href''></a>` es un hipervinculo. Dentro de href va la direccion donde quieres ser redirigido una vez precionas el boton. Podrias hacerlo funcionar como un boton que precionas mas de vez, pero para eso mejor ocupa una etiqueta hecha para eso.

```
<a href='#' onclick='addprueba(dn1)' class='button submit'>mi boton </a>

<button class='button submit' onclick='addprueba(dn1)'><button/>
```

Si no funciona escribe lo que hace el metodo addprueba tambien porfavor.

Answer (score 1):

Se mantiene pulsado debido a que es un link, entonces si un link es visitado cambia su estado a `visited`, y no vuelve a cambiar a su estado anterior.

Te sugiero que lo cambies a `button`

```
<button href class="button submit" onclick="addprueba(dni1);">Save</button>
```

si es que no tienes ninguna conveniencia.
O por otro lado puedes darle los estidos que tiene la clase button:

```
a.button:visited{
    /*Estilos de la clase .button{...}*/
}
```

Al asignarle los estilos como la clase `.button` hace que paresca que volvió a un estado anterior.

Answer (score 1):

Técnicamente este no es un botón, el elemento que tu has posteado es un elemento *anchor*  que se define como un vinculo. Un elemento botón es como el siguiente:

```
 <button> click aquí </button>
```

Ahora, tu elemento *anchor* maneja diferentes estados nativamente hablando, entre ellos; `:hover`, `:visited`, entre muchos otros mas, es aquí donde yo creo que tu elemento esta activado el estado; `:visited` y creando un efecto de "pulsado".

Podrías para esto manejar el elemento `<button>` y con ello ya no tendrías el problema

Answer (score 0):

Es por el hipervínculo, hazlo botón, más bonito y útil:

```
<button class="button submit" onclick="addprueba(dni1)" >Save</button>
```

Y ya si usas [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) para el estilo mejor aún:

```
<button class="button submit btn btn-primary" onclick="addprueba(dni1)" >Save</button>
```